# How can I use AWS Cloudwatch to get a count of a custom metric over time

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudwatch

I have code that puts a custom metric into CloudWatch. I just want to see occurrences over time. So under a specific condition our code publishes a metric:

```js
    await cloudWatchClient.send(new PutMetricDataCommand({
         MetricData: [{
             MetricName: 'MyEvent',
             Unit: 'Count',
             Timestamp: new Date(),
             Value: 1
         }],
         Namespace: 'MyNamespace'
      }));
```

(From AWS Console) So with the above I would basically select `COUNT(MyEvent)` on `MyNamespace`. I Select 3h as the timeline and I see 3 data points on the line graph. I created 3 events so that seems right. I change the dropdown to number and I get 1. Weird. I change the period to 15 minutes and I get 3. Why?

So what am I doing wrong here? I just want to be able to see a graph of the occurrences of this event over time, and, when viewing number, the total occurrences during that time period. And what's going on with `period` on the graphed metrics tab?